# Fix Fetch data form API and print it on HTML with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to fetch data from API and show it on HTML by elementID with JavaScript, Please help what I wrong in this code below.

```
<div id="priceChange"></div>

<script>
setInterval(tradestime, 5000);
function tradestime(){
fetch("https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/24hr?symbol=LTCUSDT") 
.then(
    (res) => {
        const data = res.json();
    }
)    
document.getElementById("priceChange").innerHTML = data.PriceChange;    
}
</script>
```

Please fix this code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

1. You should use `res.json()` because you want data in `JSON` format. which will return `promise` and then you can get `data`. You should read [`fetch docs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

   ```
   fetch("https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/24hr?symbol=LTCUSDT")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => el.innerHTML = data.priceChange)
   ```
2. key should be `priceChange` not `PriceChange`.
3. You can use [`parseFloat + toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) as:

   ```
   el.innerHTML = Number.parseFloat(data.priceChange).toFixed(2);
   ```

```js
setInterval(tradestime, 5000);
const el = document.getElementById("priceChange");

function tradestime() {
  fetch("https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/24hr?symbol=LTCUSDT")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => el.innerHTML = data.priceChange)
}
```

```html
<div id="priceChange"></div>
```

---

You can also use [`async-await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) here

```js
setInterval( tradestime, 5000 );
const el = document.getElementById( "priceChange" );

async function tradestime() {
  const res = await fetch( "https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/24hr?symbol=LTCUSDT" )
  const data = await res.json();
  el.innerHTML = data.priceChange;
}
```

```html
<div id="priceChange"></div>
```

Comment: It's working, but this number shows like 7.10000000. I want to show it like 7.10 How do I do that :( ??

Comment: then you can use `el.innerHTML = Number.parseFloat(data.priceChange).toFixed(2);` Answer edited. Have a look

Comment: Thank you it's working, one more thing please please help. how I remove "-" from -0.76 that showing on data.priceChange ??

Comment: just use `Math.abs` simple

Comment: yes, I get it, and working fine. The last one is how I get "-" from -0.76  that shows on data.priceChange ??

Comment: ok, I solved it with substring(0, 1), thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because `res.json()` return a Promise and because your `data` constant is visible only in your `then` block. Also, it is `priceChange` not `PriceChange` that your API is sending back. Try doing so:

```js
<div id="priceChange"></div>

<script>
  setInterval(tradestime, 5000);
  function tradestime(){
    fetch("https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/24hr?symbol=LTCUSDT") 
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
     document.getElementById("priceChange").innerHTML = data.priceChange; 
   });    
   
}
</script>
```